# Difference between Docker ENTRYPOINT and Kubernetes container spec COMMAND?

Tags: docker, containers, kubernetes, dockerfile

Dockerfile has a parameter for *ENTRYPOINT* and while writing Kubernetes deployment YAML file, there is a parameter in Container spec for *COMMAND*.

I am not able to figure out what's the difference and how each is used?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Kubernetes provides us with multiple options on how to use these commands:

When you override the default Entrypoint and Cmd in Kubernetes .yaml file, these rules apply:

- If you do not supply command or args for a Container, the defaults
  defined in the Docker image are used.
- If you supply only args for a Container, the default Entrypoint
  defined in the Docker image is run with the args that you supplied.
- If you supply a command for a Container, only the
  supplied command is used. The default EntryPoint and the default Cmd
  defined in the Docker image are ignored. Your command is
  run with the args supplied (or no args if none supplied).

*Here is an example:*

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
COPY "executable_file" /
ENTRYPOINT [ "./executable_file" ]
```

Kubernetes yaml file:

```
 spec:
    containers:
      - name: container_name
        image: image_name
        args: ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/

Answer (score 117):

The key difference is terminology. Kubernetes thought that the terms that Docker used to define the interface to
a container were awkward, and so they used different, *overlapping* terms. Since the vast majority of containers Kubernetes orchestrates are Docker, confusion abounds.

Specifically, docker entrypoints are kubernetes commands, and docker commands are kubernetes args, as indicated [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210514074330if_/https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes).

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Description                           | Docker field name | Kubernetes field name |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| The command run by the container      | Entrypoint        | command               |
| The arguments passed to the command   | Cmd               | args                  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

@Berk's description of how Kubernetes uses those runtime options is correct, but it's also correct for how docker run uses them, as long as you translate the terms. The key is to understand the interplay between image and run specifications in either system, and to translate terms whenever speaking of the other.

Comment: `Cmd` for Docker and `command` for Kubernetes when both are different things is really a bad pick

Answer (score 18):

Basically the COMMAND can override what is mentioned in the docker ENTRYPOINT

**Simple example:**

To override the dockerfile ENTRYPOINT, just add these fields to your K8s template (Look at the **command** and **args**):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: command-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-command
spec:
  containers:
  - name: command-demo-container
    image: debian
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "printenv; #OR WHATEVER COMMAND YOU WANT"]
  restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

**K8s docs:**

> command field corresponds to entrypoint in some container runtimes.
> Refer to the [Notes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes) below.

You can enter Notes link (K8s documentation for better understanding on how this command overrides the K8s ENTRYPOINT)

Answer (score 13):

The **COMMAND** in the YAML file overwrites anything mentioned in the **ENTRYPOINT** in the docker file.