# Run container in cronjob k8s

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a dockerfile finishing with an entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash" , "-c", "source /app/env.sh && printenv && python3 /app/script.py"]
```

And a yaml k8s CronJob:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my_healthcheck
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: my_healthcheck
spec:
  schedule: "30 8 * * 1-5"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 5
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: pythonscript
              image: xxx/pythonscript:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: [ <what do i put here> ]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Inside "command", what command i need to put, to run the container ?
thanks

Comment: What command do you need to run (if any)? If you're fine with just running what's in `ENTRYPOINT` just omit `command` entirely.

Comment: zerkms is right, if you don't need to overwrite what is already in your `ENTRYPOINT`, you don't need `command` at all. Are you facing any issues when running it this way ?

Comment: @zerkms and mario. thanks for the replies. Oh ok ! i thought i had to put something in "command" like it was mandatory field. I don't need to override the entrypoint so i will just get rid of  it ! thank you both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image `ENTRYPOINT` handles everything, so the `command` doesn't need to supplied.

If you do provide a `command`, it will override the `ENTRYPOINT`.

```
    command: [ '/bin/bash', '-c', 'echo "not running python"' ]
```

You can supply `args` if you want to append arguments to the `command`/`ENTRYPOINT`.

See the [difference between the Kubernetes/Docker terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316361/difference-between-docker-entrypoint-and-kubernetes-container-spec-command).

Comment: (But if you use a complex `ENTRYPOINT`/`command:` with `sh -c`, the `CMD`/`args:` are mostly entirely ignored.)

Comment: Good point. They are there, just hard to get at. `/bin/bash -c 'echo "[$0] [$1]"' some thing`