# Openshift pod terminal bash

Tags: docker, ubuntu, openshift

When running my ubuntu 20.04 image using docker I get **bash-5.0$** prompt, that is because edited .bashrc in dockerfile. When running the same image on openshift platform and go to pod terminal only get **$** prompt. If I type bash on pod terminal I get **bash-5.0$** so, what should I do to get the same prompt on first access to pod terminal on openshift?

Edit: This is the dockerfile I'm using

```
FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get -y update \
   && apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends python3 \
   && adduser python --shell /bin/bash \
   && echo 'PS1="\\s-\\v\\\$ "' >> /home/python/.bashrc

USER python

CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

Btw: Tested on Openshift 4 Local and Sandbox versions

Comment: How are you deploying your container on Openshift? Are you overriding the entrypoint by any chance? This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316361/difference-between-docker-entrypoint-and-kubernetes-container-spec-command

Comment: Hello @HiroCereal, thanks for comment!, I'm using only a cmd spec to start the container. Have updated the question

Comment: Which commands / yaml file do you use to run your image on Openshift?

Comment: I'm using oc client to build and deploy the container from dockerfile, only setting name and labels for each one